# Bd Postgres connection to Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, postgresql

I had a problem that I could not solve a few days ago, I try to connect with my Postgres bd which is on a server, I work with laravel but it has highlighted an error when I connect to my Postgres bd, this error appears

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
>   SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>   Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>   could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>   Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

**error image:**

[image]

I would like to know if it has happened the same and how to solve it, Thanks!

Comment: share your `.env` file code here

Comment: Hola este mi .env https://ibb.co/6XgSmhB

Answer (score 2):

Changing the DB_HOST to postgres, helped me to solve mine.

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=your-database-name
DB_USERNAME=user-name
DB_PASSWORD=your-password
```

Comment: I should add that this led me to a solution with Docker-compose. When specifying the host I was using 127.0.0.1 this was giving an error. The solution was to substitute the name of the service, or its `container_name` parameter. In my case, the container name was `container_name: PostgreSQL`, hence the `.env` is set as `DB_HOST=PostgreSQL`.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your *`.env`* setup like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1  //If you want to use only in localhost or otherwise change according to host server
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=your_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```

After changes of *`.env`* edit please enter this command in your terminal for clear cache:`php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without your environment file.  This error might occur because you are already connecting to postgres,

To check, make sure this line is in your .env file:

```
DB_PORT=5432
```

Or, you can remove the line from the .env and let Laravel choose the default according to the connection:

```
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
```

Another cause for failed connection due to auth is that the env file is looking for  `127.0.0.1`.  Sometimes changing this to `localhost` will help.